# Issues with positioning elements and the adjusted width of the webpage

Tags: html, css

So my website is www.jacobweyer.com

When the window becomes a certain small size, it creates a large gray area on the right side, where the header and footer wont expand to cover. How do I get rid of the large content less area while still leaving a small buffer area? I'm also having an issue where I want to have my social media buttons as far right as possible, however I want it to still stay as far right as possible until it would possibly overlap the title.

HTML

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>

    <head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

     <title>Alpha Tau Omega | Theta Omega</title>
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ATOStyle.css" />
     <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quattrocento+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

    </head>

    <body>
     <div id="header">
       <div id="innerheader">
        <div id="banner">
        </div><!-- End banner-->
        <div id="title">
        </div> <!--End title -->
        <div id="navbar">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="rush.html">Rush</a></li>
                <li><a href="history.html">History</a></li>
                <li><a href="alumni.html">Alumni</a></li>
                <li><a href="calendar.html">Calendar</a></li>
                <li><a href="media.html">Media</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div> <!--End navbar -->
     </div><!-- End innerheader -->
     <div id="outersocial">
     <div id="social">
       <ul>
            <li>
            <img src="./pieces/socialmedia/facebook.png" />   
            </li>
            <li>
            <img src="./pieces/socialmedia/twitter.png" />   
            </li>
            <li>
            <img src="./pieces/socialmedia/youtube.png" />
            </li>
      </ul>
    </div> <!-- End social-->
    </div> <!--End outersocial -->
    </div> <!-- End header -->

    <div id="pagecenter">
    </div> <!-- End pagecenter -->

    <div id="footer">
    <div id="footercontent">
        <div id="footerbanner1">
        </div> <!--end footerbanner1-->
        <div id="footernav">
        <p> Alpha Tau Omega Fraternity | Theta Omega Chapter | Northern Kentucky University | <a href="contactus.html">Contact Us!</a></p>
        </div> <!-- End footernav-->           
        <div id="footerbanner2">
        </div> <!-- End footerbanner2-->
    </div> <!--end footercontent -->
    </div> <!--end footer-->
    </body>
    </html>
```

CSS

```
     body {
     height: 100%;
     width: 100%;
     margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
     background-color: #808080
     }

      /* Header Container */
     #header {
      background:url(./pieces/headerBar.png);
     position: static;    
     width:100%;
     height:139px;
     padding:0;
     z-index: 10000;
     }

     /* Container inside the header for sorting elements */
     #innerheader {
     height: 139px;
      width: 750px;
       margin-right: auto;
      margin-left: auto;
         position: relative;
     }
       /* The following is the Nav Bar */
      #navbar {
     position: relative;
   top: 76px;
     left: 210px;
    margin-left: inherit;
       }
      #navbar ul {
      list-style-type: none; 
   margin: 0px; 
   padding: 0px;
         }

       #navbar ul li {
      font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
  text-decoration: none;
        color: #000000; 
   display: inline-block; 
   width: 50px; 
   height: 20px;    
   margin: 10px;
       }

       #navbar ul li a {
       text-decoration: none; 
   color: black;  
       }

       #navbar ul li a:hover {
       color: white;
       }

       /*The following is the Intertwine Banner */
       #banner {
       background:url(./pieces/banner.png); 
   position: absolute; 
   margin-left: 0px; 
   min-height: 193px;
       min-width: 183px;
       background-repeat: no-repeat;
       }

       /* Alpha Tau Omega - Theta Omega Title */
      #title {
      position: absolute;
      background: url(./pieces/name.png);
      margin-left: 190px;
      min-height: 75px;
      min-width: 285px;
      }

    /* The following are the social media icons */
    #outersocial{
position:;
left:50%;
height: 139px;
width:50%;
    }

   #social {
    position: absolute;  
top: 2px;
right: 10px;
    }

   #social ul {
    list-style-type: none;
     }

    #social li{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 36px;
    height: auto;
    margin: 5px;
    }
    #social img {
width: 36px;
height: auto;
    }

    /* Pagecenter is where the content will be on the web page*/
    #pagecenter {
    position: static;
     margin-right: auto;
     margin-left: auto;
 height: 50px;
     width: 750px;
     min-height: 1000px;
     background:url(./pieces/mainBG.png);
     background-position: center;
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     background-attachment: fixed;
     margin-top: -19px;
 z-index:50
    }

    /* The following is the footer and its content */
    #footer {
    margin-top: 20px;
    padding-top: 30px;
    background: url(./pieces/footerbar.png);
    height: 77px;
    width: 100%;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    clear: both;
    bottom: 0px;
    position: static;
    }

    #footerbanner1 {
    background: url(./pieces/footerbanner.png);
    position: absolute;
    min-height: 95px;
    min-width: 90px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
margin-top: -30px;
left: 10px;
    }

    #footerbanner2 {
background: url(./pieces/footerbanner.png);
    position: absolute;
    min-height: 95px;
    min-width: 90px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
margin-top: -30px;
right: 10px;
    }

    #footercontent {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
right: 5px;
left: 5px;
    }

    #footernav {
font-family: 'Quattrocento Sans', sans-serif;
position: absolute;
text-align: center;
right: 15%;
left: 15%;
    }

    #footernav p {
margin: 0px;
padding-right: 25%;
padding-left: 25%;
font-family: 'Quattrocento Sans', sans-serif;
color: white;
position: relative;
    }

    #footernav a {
font-family: 'Quattrocento Sans', sans-serif;
color: white;
    }

    #footernav a:hover {
color: orange;  
    }
```

Comment: can you put your code in jsfiddle and post that url?

Answer (score 0):

An object is just a special kind of data, with properties and methods.
Object properties can be any of the three primitive data types, or any of the abstract data types, such as another object. Object properties are usually variables that are used internally in the object's methods, but can also be globally visible variables that are used throughout the page.

The syntax for adding a property to an object is:

objectName.objectProperty = propertyValue;

Example1. :

```
person=new Object();
person.firstname="stack";
person.lastname="overflow";
person.age=50;
person.color="black";
```

Example2 :

```
var message="Hello India!";
var x=message.length;
```

here .length is the property of object message.

I hope it will be helpful to you.